# DOMPDF fonts error: src/Renderer/Text.php on line 105

Tags: wordpress, pdf, fonts, permissions, dompdf

I am using DomPDF and I am having a issue. Relate fonts 
This is error: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: ...../pdf/lib/fonts\Times-Bold in ....wp-content/plugins/custom_plugin/pdf/src/Renderer/Text.php on line 105
[image]
Is it working correct on localhost, but not on live site. I think that is something relate to permission.
I checked permission on folder contain all fonts (custom fonts): 0755 and font file is 0644.
Please help me and thank any help.

Answer (score 0):

It is fixed when I clone all file from github, and install direct to live server.
FIXED